# How Can I setText in the EditText without knowing id?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I'd like use the `setText()` function  for an `EditText` without knowing the id,
so if there are three `EditText` in an application, the command `setText()` should change the text on all three and I won't know the ids.

I was planning to use this command:

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findView (something);
```

I don't think it is that simple.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the `TextViews` alone inside a `ViewGroup` (i.e. `LinearLayout`) and iterate along their children like this.-

```
for (int i = 0; i < containerView.getChildCount(); i ++) {
    View view = containerView.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof TextView) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText(yourText);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I have to explain myself better,
I would like to make an application that changes the EditText of other apps (programs) (such as the program for texting), so I do not know the Id of EditText and I cannot connect to the LinearLayout to another app.

Comment: Mmh, that's a totally different scenario indeed. I don't think such a thing could be doable, or at least I don't know any way to.

Comment: do you know if there's a way to change or set something on other applications? maybe you know someone who could know how to do? maybe a guide ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not possible. As far as I know, information can be shared between different apps through `ContentProviders`, yet they won't let you to manipulate the app the way you're looking for.

Comment: And if I wanted to just add the text without changing it:
For example: a person is typing a message to one, and after five seconds my program adds ( by using the command append ("text")) a string like "hello"